# Creating SQL table in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to create a table for every number that messages me one particular text say "R:".When I receive this message it should call another activity passing it the number of sent person.I am using intent for this and name of table should be the 'U'+number.But it is an error to assign non static variable to static variable.If I remove static it is asking for static variable.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter extends ActionBarActivity{
static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Users";
static  String DATABASE_TABLE = "";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

 String DATABASE_CREATE ="";

final Context context;

DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Intent in=getIntent();
String num=in.getStringExtra("num");
String date=in.getStringExtra("date");

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        try {
            DATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+num+"(date VARCHAR,latitude VARCHAR,longitude VARCHAR);";
            DATABASE_CREATE="";
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Show us some reveland code & [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried to add image but couldn't  give me few min i will

Comment: You can just copy the code or upload it to another site like imageshack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next line is full of errors

```
DATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+num+"(date VARCHAR,latitude VARCHAR,longitude VARCHAR);"; // FULL OF ERRORS!!
```

It should be something like

```
DATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table" + num + " (date TEXT, latitude TEXT, longitude TEXT)";
```

So, correct the table creation and delete the 
Then, the next line sets the table creation to an EMPTY String

```
DATABASE_CREATE=""; // EMPTY!! This one is then executed on next line!!
```

Which is then executed:

```
db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
```

Which is equivalent to

```
db.execSQL("");
```

So, correct the table creation string and delete `DATABASE_CREATE="";`

Comment: okay but it is asking for a num to be static varible but it cannot be static

Comment: It is giving an error in is not static

Comment: Intent cannot be static

Comment: If i make num static it is asking to make in static, if i do that it is giving error getintent method is not static and cannot make in as static

Comment: The string num is getting its value from intent variable 'in'. So it is saying cannot make static reference to non static variable 'in'. If i make 'in' static it is saying getIntent is non static method

Comment: Move this `String num=in.getStringExtra("num");` inside your `onCreate()` method, before everything else